# Foreign key matching in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

Just curious, if I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "post" (
    "id" SERIAL,
    "revision" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "summary" CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    "description" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL
        REFERENCES "user" ("id") MATCH FULL
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    "post_type_id" INTEGER NOT NULL
        REFERENCES "post_type" ("id") MATCH FULL
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    "ctime" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    PRIMARY KEY("id", "revision")
);
```

to store posts, and this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "post_state" (
    "post_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "assembly_seat_id" INTEGER NOT NULL
        REFERENCES "assembly_seat" ("id") MATCH FULL
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    PRIMARY KEY("post_id")
);
```

and I want my `post_id` field to point to `post(id)`, how do I do it? I have tried with the following phrase:

```
    "post_id" INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        REFERENCES "post" ("id") MATCH SIMPLE
            ON UPDATE RESTRICT
            ON DELETE RESTRICT,
```

but I am getting this error:

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "post"

The values of `post_state(asembly_seat_id)` do not change in this case.

Comment: You can only create a foreign key that references a single row in the other table. Since `post_id` is not unique (only the post_id/revision combination is unique), you can't reference it.

Comment: OH, thanks for the reply, silly me *facepalm*

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: You may be interested in my answer that contradicts your comment in parts.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yea, re-modeled the tables already :) still thanks for the answer tho

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I didn't say anything about single columns in the foreign key, just that it needs to reference a _single row_ (which is exactly what you changed it to do :) ). There are (as far as I know) basically two ways of making it reference a unique row, either make it reference the composite primary key or add a unique index to the column (post.id) he was trying to reference. Adding unique breaks the primary key in post and the foreign key change breaks what I was reading that he was attempting to do, hang a post_state on a post, not a specific revision of a post.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Oh, you are absolutely right. I misread your "single row" as "single column". Will fix my incorrect quote immediately. My apologies.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter np, I realized you misread, just wanted to set things straight :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A foreign key constraint can span **multiple columns**. You could just add the column `revision` to the table `post_state`.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE post (
  post_id serial NOT NULL
 ,revision integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 ,summary text NOT NULL
 ,description text NOT NULL
 ,user_id integer NOT NULL
    REFERENCES user (id) MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
 ,post_type_id integer NOT NULL
    REFERENCES post_type (id) MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
 ,ctime timestamptz DEFAULT NOW()
 ,PRIMARY KEY(post_id, revision)
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE post_state (
  post_id integer NOT NULL
 ,revision integer NOT NULL
 ,assembly_seat_id integer NOT NULL
    REFERENCES assembly_seat (id) MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
 ,PRIMARY KEY(post_id, revision)
 ,FOREIGN KEY (post_id, revision) REFERENCES post (post_id, revision)
);
```

Read the manual about [foreign key constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK).

I am using the name `post_id` for the primary key column of table `post`. Don't use `id` as column name. If you join a bunch of tables you end up with a bunch of columns all names `id`. Regrettably, some half-wit ORMs are in the habit of doing that.

Alternatively, it might be **better design** to have **unique `post_id`** in table `post` and add a table `post_revision` with a n:1 relation to `post`.

Comment: Excellent answer. SQL is easy: *once you master the syntax, everything reduces to a data modelling problem*

Comment: @Erwin yea, I actually re-designed the model and have another post_revision table as you mentioned :P